# openface alignlib in python

Tags: python, dlib

I know it is  most silly question for openface But I am new to openface and I am not abe to figure this out

```
align = openface.AlignDlib()
```

what do we need to pass in the arguements . In openface docoumentation it is written

```
align = openface.AlignDlib(args.dlibFacePredictor)
```

and it says in its docoumentation , argument is a dtring which is path to dlib's .

I dont know what that means its my first programm for openface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is expected to lead to some pretrained model (residing on your harddisk). Some dlib-models are listed [here](https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models) (official developer).

In terms of openface, the [code](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/models/get-models.sh#L21) shows:

```
mkdir -p dlib
if [ ! -f dlib/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat ]; then
  printf "\n\n====================================================\n"
  printf "Downloading dlib's public domain face landmarks model.\n"
  printf "Reference: https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models\n\n"
  printf "This will incur about 60MB of network traffic for the compressed\n"
  printf "models that will decompress to about 100MB on disk.\n"
  printf "====================================================\n\n"
  wget -nv \
       http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2 \
       -O dlib/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2
  [ $? -eq 0 ] || die "+ Error in wget."
  bunzip2 dlib/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2
  [ $? -eq 0 ] || die "+ Error using bunzip2."
fi
```

Meaning: it's **shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat** (part of above list).

You can look into the code for additional understanding, e.g. [here](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/71ee6ee7477be8fe2a2865b5b60fdfef52cf5783/evaluation/lfw-classification-unknown.py#L355):

```
def __init__(self, inputDir, outputDir, verbose):
    self.inputDir = inputDir
    self.dlibFacePredictor = os.path.join(
        dlibModelDir, "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
```

Comment: so , i can just git clone dlib models https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models in my computer and copy the path of required model  like this openface.AlignDlib(path)

Comment: Yes, but you only need the one and not the full list. (and also: if you installed openface, it already downloaded this one; or else it won't be working) **edit** and you need to decompress it probably (at least openface is doing that using bunzip2 ).

Comment: yes , i found the shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks in dlib folder of openface , but it is in .tar form , do we need to extract it ?

Comment: I don't know (and i don't know why you got a tar). I would expect you need the original .dat (not tar). But just try it. You will see an IO-error probably. In regards to those things: what's bad about just trying it. With the general idea of *maybe i need decompression*, potential errors are easily debugged.

Comment: a='/home/arshad/openface/models/dlib/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2'
align = openface.AlignDlib(a) ,   This is the code i wrote and got the error -    in __init__
    self.predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(facePredictor)
RuntimeError: Unexpected version found while deserializing dlib::shape_predictor

Comment: and yes it is .dat not .tar

Comment: I told you. Decompress it (or just use the path to the existing dat).

Comment: in __init__
    self.predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(facePredictor)
RuntimeError: Unexpected version found while deserializing dlib::shape_predictor. 

this is the error i get

Comment: After decomprssion it works , .dat file directly was giving serializing error . thanks a lot for help